# Pagination support in visualize.js

Tags: jasper-reports, visualize

I have a question related to pagination in [visualize.js](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/visualizejs)

I have a report which is rendered using iframe and have top toolbar with pagination and export options (see jasper_iframe.png), sample code below

```
<div class="its-preloader-reports">
<iframe src="http://localhost:8080/jasperserver-pro/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&reportUnit=/public/Exchange/reports/Report1&decorate=no&enterpriseId=11&startTime=28/05/2015%2000:00:00&endTime=28/05/2015%2023:59:00&name=itmsadmin%20quwic&report_type=3" height="867px" width="960px"> </iframe>
```

[image: jasper_iframe]

Same report when I convert this report to visualize.js the top toolbar is gone (see jasper_visualize.png), sample code below

```
visualize({
server: "http://localhost:8080/",
auth: {
    name: "superuser",
    password: "superuser"
}
},function (v) {
v("#container").report({
    resource: "/public/Exchange/reports/Report1",
    params: {
         "enterpriseId": ["21"],
         "startTime": ["01/04/2015 00:00:00"],
         "endTime": ["03/04/2015 23:59:00"],
         "name": ["itmsadmin quwic"],
         "report_type=3": ["3"]
    },
    error: handleError

});
function handleError(err) {
    console.log('error:'+err.message);
}
```

});

[image: jasper_visualize.png]

My question is does Visualize.js has native support of this toolbar or we have to implement it on our own? Any explanation would be really appreciated